# python datetime.utcnow not showing correct timestamp

Tags: python, datetime

I can't wrap my head around this.

Assuming that unixtime is total seconds since 1970.1.1, why does datetime.utcnow().timestamp() return different number?

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.utcnow()
>>> print(now.timestamp())
1492525439.406112
>>> print((now-datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds())
1492536239.406112
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a time zone problem.

The difference between the two values is exactly 10,600 seconds, which is exactly three hours.

`utcnow` is in the UTC time zone. `datetime` uses the local machine time zone. Change them both to use the same time base and you will see there is no longer a difference.

You could change `datetime.utcnow` to `datetime.now`, or change `datetime(...)` to `datetime(...).replace(tzinfo=...)`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the OS.

[See this link It has the same timestamp](https://repl.it/HOWy/0)